# Automatic size image to max TD size

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, html-table

I'm trying to workaround a limitation in SharePoint that can have Only 3 columns in their layout and I need four.
Therefore, I created a 2 columns layout and in each cell, I'm adding a table like this.
I want the image to fit entirely into the TD.
If you look at the image in front of "Effort 1", it resizes to the height available.
I would like it to fit entirely within the cell (like in the empty cell in front of "Effort 3".

It looks like it is taking the current height of cell 2 and fits to the same size.
However, the max size should be the empty cell in front of "Effort 3" and I want the image to fit entirely in it ( like the last image).

```html
<table style="width:100%;border:0;table-layout:fixed;word-wrap:break-word;border-collapse:collapse;" width="100 %">
    <tbody>
         <tr>
        <td width="100 %">
        <img align="center" width="100 %" src="/url/EmbeddedImage160142.jpg">
        </td>
        <td width="100 %"><h3>Effort 1</h3><p>A description of an effort and why it matters  </p>
        </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>

I tried various syntaxes. but the problem I have is that the image does not automatically resize to
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This doesnt look like tabular data to me and as such you shouldnt use a `table` unless it is for e-mail templating. Why do you need to use a table? Cant you just use CSS-Grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected some error in your code this is the solution.

```html
<table style="width:100%;border:0;table-layout:fixed;word-wrap:break-word;border-collapse:collapse;" width="100 %">
    <tbody>
         <tr>
        <td width="50%">
            <img style="display:block; width:100%;" src="https://placeimg.com/100/100/any">
        </td>
        <td width="50%" style="vertical-align:top"><h3>Effort 1</h3><p>A description of an effort and why it matters  </p>
        </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: works perfecty. Thank you for the solution and your quick reactivity